# Custom overflow scroll bar module

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, scroll, overflow

I have a Drupal site with a div that has overflow hidden. I want the content to be scrollable sideways but not with that ugly light colored scroll bar. My site is mainly dark so I want something dark and not very noticeable.

I have searched for hours but none of the normal jquery plugins seem to work. I have tried installing any one i find but they all end up the same way. No scroll bar at all. So does anyone know of a module for drupal or why the plugins arent working?

Answer (score 0):

You may try [**jQuery Custom Scrollbar**](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) plugin for your website.

[**SEE DEMO**](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) In action.

**USAGE:**

Include Following in `<head>` :

```
<link href="path-to-latest/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="path-to-latest/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path-to-latest/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script src="path-to-latest/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="path-to-latest/custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>

<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).load(function(){
            $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({
                scrollButtons:{
                    enable:true
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Your Contents should be inside the following `<div>`:

```
<div id="content_1" class="content">
    /* Your content */
</div>
```

[**SEE EXAMPLE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/nwfpy/)

Comment: I tried doing exactly what that told me to do and no bar showed up or anything.

Comment: I dont have the code anymore. Not for that one. The most recent one i tried was jScrollPane.

Comment: How `jQuery Custom Scrollbar` plugins is working? See this Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/nwfpy/

Comment: That jsfiddle doesnt have the scroll bar for me

Answer (score 0):

I used jScrollPane without any fuss and best thing is that it works

[jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com)

You can also do custom themes.

Comment: i tried just the basic jscrollpane without any customizing and no bar showed up at all to scroll.

Comment: try to use nicescroll pane ,it is very easy to access. $('html').niceScroll({cursorborder:"",cursorcolor:"#333333",cursorwidth:"8px", boxzoom:true, autohidemode:false});


 preservenativescrolling: false,
        cursorwidth: '8px',
        cursorborder: 'none',
        cursorborderradius:'0px',
        cursorcolor:"#39CCDB",
        autohidemode: false, 
        background:"#999999"
})